# array_diff_uassoc () in PHP?

Tags: php, html

```
function myfunction($v1, $v2) {
    if ($v1 == $v2) {
        return 0;
    }
    if ($v1 > $v2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return-1;
    }
}

$a1 = array(5 => "Rat", 2 => "Cat", 7 => "Horse");
$a2 = array(8 => "Rat",4 => "Cat",7 => "Horse");
print_r(array_diff_uassoc($a1, $a2, "myfunction"));
```

How it is executed?

Comment: Can you mention what is your question too?

Comment: What kind of work function do this one?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  Are you trying to ask how to trigger your function?

Comment: Ok same thing tell to me

Comment: I need more information, _what are you trying to do_.

Answer (score 3):

Please read the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-uassoc.php).

> It basically compares two or more arrays, checking for differences, before comparing the keys in a user-defined function, then returns an array with the keys and values from the first array, if the function allows it.
>
> Unlike [array_diff_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) an user supplied callback function is used for the indices comparison, not internal function.

Please see the live version of your code [here](http://ideone.com/miJ7z). It calculates the difference based on the function and gives the following output.

```
Array
(
    [5] => Rat
    [2] => Cat
)
```

Answer (score 0):

check out [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-uassoc.php) more information about your program if you couldn't understand it